# Get Android phone apps on tablet

Tags: installation

I have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus that I use on a day-to-day basis, and I just received a new Galaxy Tab as a gift. I would like to install largely the same apps on both devices. Is there an easy way to accomplish this, preferably automated?

Answer (score 3):

Factory-reset your Galaxy Tab. Then, log-in using the Google account your Nexus is using. It should ask you if you want to download or synchronize the apps that you have installed on your Galaxy Nexus.